# date setting in datetime picker

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

I am using `DateTimePicker` control. When I select date I want date as `20 Feb 2013`, instead I am getting `20-2-2013` or `2/20/2013`.

I tried different functions of `DateTimePicker`.

I kept `Format` option of `DateTimePicker` as `Short`.

```
dtpSaudaDate.value.Date.ToShortDateString();    
dtpSaudaDate.value.Date.ToOADate();
```

None of the function worked. Is there any specific method to get date in that format? [ 28 Feb 2013 ]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you tried

```
dtpSaudaDate.value.Date.ToString("dd MMM yyyy");
```

For more formats:

http://www.dotnetperls.com/datetime-format

Comment: well your answer is more near, I worked it out, I got it as 28 February 2013 while for comaring values in database are 28 Feb 2013. Can i get it as 28 Feb 2013 instead of 28 February 2013

Comment: for Feb just use MMM instead of MMMM

Comment: @Sagar it is good practice to accept only right answers. If user give you a right answer in comments -> ask him update a his answer before you accept it.

Comment: @VARAK update a answer too, if make a correction of this in comments, please

Comment: @Sagar, just to make clear - I am not upvoted your question :), welcome anyway

Comment: @Fabio yeah , i got it from lazybere... But thanx for suggetion.

Answer (score 3):

1. Set `Format` property of `DateTimePicker` to `Custom`
2. Set `CustomFormat` property to `dd MMM yyyy`

---

UPDATE (month formatting for DateTime)

- `M` is a month, from 1 through 12 (2)
- `MM` is a month, from 01 through 12 (02)
- `MMM` is **abbreviated** name of the month (Feb)
- `MMMM` is **full** name of the month (February)

Comment: Can i get it as 28 Feb 2013 instead of 28 February 2013 ?

Comment: @Sagar I don't understand why you marked answer with `MMMM` as correct, if your requirement was `28 Feb 2013`

Comment: after that i asked him for 28 FEB according to my database requirements. He suggested me right thing. Hence i accepted. There is No point to downvote me.

Comment: @Sagar `dd MMM yyyy` is a *right* sing. `dd MMMM yyyy` will give full month name. And here is point for downvoting - question was incorrect. You should ask for `28 February 2013` instead

Comment: If you read my question carefully i asked for 20 Feb 2013[This kind of format]. And After watching your upvotes i also commented on your answer asking that. You can see my first comment also. But there was no reply from you. But VARAX gave me reply in time and i got solution. Thats why i accepted it. No point in downvoting my question.

Comment: But I seen his answer first and with example. Thats why it helped me. No daubt your answer is correct. Even i am saying that if i had enopugh reputation i had also upvoted your your answer. and if you had given this cooment >>"my answer is in format you asked" after my first comment then it was ok.

Comment: @Sagar I already removed downvote from your question, that's up to you to decide which answer is correct. As I understood from question, you had problem with `DateTimePicker` control, not with converting any `DateTime` object to string.

Comment: @Sagar Yes, I understood that actually your question worth downvoting :) `date setting in datetime picker` completely misleading title. DateTimePicker has nothing to question

Comment: hahaha... do you give answers by reading just titles? well by looking at your reputation it doesnt seems so.